# Sql server XQuery sql:variable and bit data type

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, xquery

The following query returns `<s>false</s>`. However I expect it returns `<s>0</s>`. Is it a way to do it?

```
declare @b bit = 0
declare @xml xml = '<x></x>';
select @xml.query('<s>{sql:variable("@b")}</s>')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @b bit = 0
declare @xml xml = '<x></x>';
select @xml.query('<s>{xs:int(sql:variable("@b"))}</s>')
```

[Constructor Functions (XQuery)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189547.aspx)